# Rounding numbers

Tags: php

My question is how would I round the output of The script below to display 107.4 instead of 107.44613075316  I found the php round function but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
    ///// Get the two locations from the url

$lat1 = $_GET[lat1];
$lon1 = $_GET[lon1];

$lat2 = $_GET[lat2];
$lon2 = $_GET[lon2];


//////calculate the distance

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +
        cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}

// Miles
echo distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "m") . " miles<br><br>";

//Kilometers
echo distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "k") . " kilometers<br><br>";

//Nautical miles
echo distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "N") . " Nautical miles";
```

Comment: Please read the manual: http://php.net/round, there are examples given even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP manual is very clear in how to use the round() method.

The simplest way to round it automatically would be within your distance function, although it's arguable that you would want full precision from this method.. If you don't, then use the following which will automatically round the output:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +
        cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    $output = $miles;
    if ($unit == "K") {
        $output = $miles * 1.609344;
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        $output = $miles * 0.8684;
    }
    return round($output, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rudi_visser that worked. The only problem I found was the Parenthesis: $output = $miles * 1.609344);  but after I removed it worked like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: @JustinPetty Great :) Updated the answer to not have the error, sorry about that.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this option. This would result in EVERY call to `distance()` to round the result, what if you needed the more precise value in other code-points? Maybe add a precision flag.

Comment: @MikePurcell hence me stating `although it's arguable that you would want full precision from this method`. It would be beneficial to have an extra (defaulted) flag on the method, yes. But it depends what the OP is going to do with the result anyway.

Comment: Lol, see that now. Every time I see code my eyes train right to it and skip the text.

Answer (score 2):

[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is the general-purpose fix here.

To print a floating point number to 1 decimal of precision for display, for example:

```
sprintf("%2.1f miles <br /><br />", $distance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `number_format()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php round(107.44613075316, 1); ?>
```

should do it. And you can use:

to round up, for instance. More information on the modes and round :

https://www.php.net/round

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

```
$x=107.44613075316;
echo(round($x,1) . "\n");
```

The output is, of course, `107.4`.

Documentation is your friend: read it. Love it. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Round value x to precision p, where 0 < p < infinite. (f.ex. 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2,…)

## PHP

```
function RoundTo(float $x, float $p)
{
  $y = 1/$p;
  return intval(($x+(1/($y+$y)))*$y)/$y;
}

function RoundUp(float $x, float $p)
{
  $y = 1/$p;
  return intval(($x+(1/$y))*$y)/$y;
}

function RoundDown(float $x, float $p)
{
  $y = 1/$p;
  return intval($x*$y)/$y;
}
```